# Centos 6.5, PXE Boot fails to recognize the SSD device

Tags: ssd, pxe-boot

Goal:
Add correct ahci/scsi to my initrd for PXE install of OS.

I am using Centos6.5 minimal install ISO. I have a Serial interface only (no VGA), new low cost rangley processor system and need to boot over PXE and install images. At present all goes through well, except when it comes to the finding devices to install linux onto, none found! I am sure for some reason we are missing the ahci/scsi version from intel to support this. The device is an SSD - ATA-8: TS64GSSD25S-M, 110512E, max UDMA/133

two questions:

1. Anyone know the correct driver version needed?
2. How do i build this into the initrd file, i have read multiple articles now, some useful but the files on  initrd.img are now slightly changed. I have tried booting using my own, it comes up and finally dracut comes in there and complains about `root=` to which i added `root=/dev/sda1` but still crashed later on.
3. Reviewing all the files when i build this for mkinitrd, Dracut shows up in  the initrd.img i build vs the standard initrd.img for pxeboot is significantly different?

Log excerpt using recent driver to prove i can at least see this device/controller:

```
[    2.528571] igb 0000:00:14.3: LRO is disabled
[    2.528575] igb 0000:00:14.3: Using MSI-X interrupts. 1 rx queue(s), 1 tx queue(s)
[    2.528600] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
[    2.528702] ahci 0000:00:17.0: irq 52 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.529122] igb 0000:01:00.0: irq 53 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.529134] igb 0000:01:00.0: irq 54 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.543100] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 4 ports 3 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[    2.543108] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq led clo pio sxs deso sadm sds apst
[    2.543120] ahci 0000:00:17.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.543837] scsi0 : ahci
[    2.543960] scsi1 : ahci
[    2.544069] scsi2 : ahci
[    2.544164] scsi3 : ahci
```

Thanks for pointers.